# Views not visible in Relativelayout

Tags: android, xml, android-relativelayout

[This is the layout image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKyQ4.jpg) I am trying to add text,three vertical lines on an image in Relative layout. 
View's with ID's , Leftline and rightline are not visible where as view with ID cardline is visible. How can I make all the views visible ?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp">
        <!--app:cardBackgroundColor="#000000"-->


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp">




            <ImageView
                android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
                android:id="@+id/main_image_story"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/contentdescimage"
                android:src="@drawable/vijaymallya"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/leftline"
                android:layout_width="4dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#f49a32"/>


            <View
                android:id="@+id/rightline"
                android:layout_width="4dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="#f49a32"/>




            <View
                android:id="@+id/cardline"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="6dp"
                android:background="#f49a32" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/cardline"
                android:background="@drawable/background_gradient"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/date_story"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:shadowColor="#000000"
                    android:shadowRadius="2"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    tools:text="9.30 PM, 28 APRIL 2017" />



            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@drawable/background_gradient2"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="5dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="11dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
                            android:background="#ffffff"/>

                    </LinearLayout>


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/substory_title_story"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:lineSpacingExtra="0sp"
                        android:shadowColor="#000000"
                        android:shadowRadius="2"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        tools:text="Vijay Mallya Misled Us On Wealth, Says Supreme Court, Hauls Him For Contempt" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tags"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="6" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/number_of_articles_story"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="4"
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:shadowColor="#000000"
                        android:shadowRadius="2"
                        android:textColor="#f49a32"
                        android:textSize="11sp"
                        tools:text="7 ARTICLES - EXPLORE" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>


     </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: your `CardView` has `layout_height="wrap_content"` and `RelativeLayout` has `layout_height="match_parent"` .... it obviously doesn't make sens ... why ? You told parent view to be as long as direct child and also told the child view to be as long as it parent ... it means that height cannot be calculated

Comment: Changed relative layout to be wrap content, Views still not visible

Comment: @Jani can u pls upload layout image here?

Comment: @LokeshDesai added the layout image

Comment: @Jani Please check my ans..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this changes..i have tried in my demo app it is working

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/main_image_story"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/dubai" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/leftline"
                    android:layout_width="4dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:background="#f49a32" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/rightline"
                    android:layout_width="4dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:background="#f49a32" />
            </FrameLayout>


            <View
                android:id="@+id/cardline"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="6dp"
                android:background="#f49a32" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/cardline"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/date_story"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:shadowColor="#000000"
                    android:shadowRadius="2"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    tools:text="9.30 PM, 28 APRIL 2017" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="5dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="11dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
                            android:background="#ffffff" />

                    </LinearLayout>


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/substory_title_story"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:lineSpacingExtra="0sp"
                        android:shadowColor="#000000"
                        android:shadowRadius="2"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        tools:text="Vijay Mallya Misled Us On Wealth, Says Supreme Court, Hauls Him For Contempt" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tags"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="6" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/number_of_articles_story"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="4"
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:shadowColor="#000000"
                        android:shadowRadius="2"
                        android:textColor="#f49a32"
                        android:textSize="11sp"
                        tools:text="7 ARTICLES - EXPLORE" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this will help u...if not than pls let me know...will find other way...

Comment: thanks, it works . But can you tell me what was the issue in my previous code ?

Comment: @Jani First thing U have image view with property match_parent....scale type=fitxy and adjustviewbound=true...that's why ur relativelayout allow image to cover both views left and right...nothing else...otherwise ur code is good

Comment: In framelayout you provided as well , I made scale type=fitxy and adjustviewbound=true for the image to not shrink (image is shrinking otherwise), Views are visible in this case. I had to make adjustviewbound= true, else my image was shrinking . Why is it happening only with relative layout ?

Comment: no no ur code is good ...every layout has their own behaviour framelayout will display layout layer wise so for ur requirement it is perfect to use it....

Answer (score 0):

use padding and margin according to your layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
  .....
</LinearLayout>
```